# Custom Font Awesome Icons No Longer Working in Wordpress On Certain Browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

My website http://goesllc.com is using wordpress and the theme I have installed already included font awesome icons. I created a custom set and added them to my theme. They were all working fine, but the custom ones I added randomly stopped showing up in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

The icons still show perfectly in Safari, Opera, and my mobile android browser.

If you go to the site in Chrome and look below the slider on the homepage you can see where there are supposed to be icons, but instead it just shows letters. There are 3 icons that are supposed to be on that page, but instead they show the letters, "a", "e", and "d". If i were to switch to the fontawesome icons the theme had pre-installed they show up fine.

However, in Safari or Opera the icons shows perfectly as intended. I've contacted my theme's author and have been searching around for a fix, but to no avail.

Anybody have any idea why the icons stopped showing up in certain browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with serving up web fonts from other servers. In your case, the goes-font is being served up from http://goesassets.com which is a different domain, and is being blocked by a cross-origin policy.

Either move those fonts into a directory on the http://goesllc.com server and load them from there, or set up a CORS policy on http://goesassets.com to serve them up.

There are plenty of articles online to set up CORS policies via apache configuration files, .htaccess, etc if you go that route.